# ASP User ID in HLink as querystring

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm pulling my hair out with something quite simple, basically I'm trying to send the current logged on username from an ASP.Net site to another page as a querystring. I had this working from a redirect on a button in the VB code, but I need it working in the aspx page now.

```
<asp:HyperLink  ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="My Details" NavigateUrl="/wfMyDetails.aspx?UserID=<%: Membership.GetUser().UserName %>" />
```

The link works but its passing the <%: Membership.GetUser().UserName %> literally instead of getting the user name. I've tried this several different ways but none seem to have worked so far.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and I may retain some hair...

Thanks, Jon.

Comment: Just a comment from a security perspective - bear in mind that a user can change the user-name and access the "wfMyDetails" page for a different user. Not sure if that's a concern in your situation or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use nested Code in Servertags!

You have to set the Navigate URL in CodeBehind, for example on PageLoad!

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "/wfMyDetails.aspx?UserID=" & Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

Or you just use a normal `<a>` Tag:

```
<a href="/wfMyDetails.aspx?UserID=<%: Membership.GetUser().UserName %>">MyLink</a>
```

Comment: I ended up doing it like this: 

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        lnkMyDet.NavigateUrl = "/wfMyDetails.aspx?UserID=" & Membership.GetUser().UserName
    End Sub

Thanks